# Accessing arguments object using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), I should be able to do the following:

```
const test = (a, b, c, d) => {
    console.log(...arguments);
}

test(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

However, I'm getting the actual arguments object, not `[1,2,3,4]`.

How do I do this using ES6?

Comment: arrow functions don't have "arguments"  - so `arguments` must be coming from some outer containing function you haven't shown

Comment: Once you fix that, you'd never get `[1,2,3,4]`, console would have `1 2 3 4`

Comment: read [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) documentation, especially the very fist sentence

Comment: try `const test = (...args) => {
    console.log(...args);
}` for a similar experience

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not trying to refer to an outer scope. I simply want the arguments object that you would get from `Array.prototype.call(arguments)`

Comment: I know you are not trying to do that, however, I'm saying that's what you are getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Arrow functions do not bind an arguments object Thus, arguments is simply a reference to the name in the enclosing scope.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Use a `function` statement instead:

```js
function test() {
  console.log(...arguments);
}

test(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in ES 6:

```
const test = (...args) => {
    console.log(...args);
}

test(1, 2, 3, 4)
```